# Webpack Error: Cannot find module "."

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

I am using the api from [musixmatch-sdk](https://github.com/musixmatch/musixmatch-sdk) and have an error by building my project with `webpack`.

I am using `webpack 2`, `react`, `node`.

The default `import` on the `musixmatch` site is:

```
var MusixmatchApi = require('../../build/javascript-client/src/index');
```

But this does't work and getting this error:

```
ERROR in ./build/javascript-client/src/index.js<br/>
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ApiClient' in '/Users/myname/lyrix/build/javascript-client/src'<br/>
     @ ./build/javascript-client/src/index.js 28:4-2099<br/>
     @ ./src/server.js
```

So I have wrote it with an absolute path like:

```
const MusixmatchApi = require(path.join(__dirname,'../build/javascript-client/src/index'));
```

This works in development mode of `webpack`, but i get this warning:

```
WARNING in ./src/server.js
    33:20-102 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
     @ ./src/server.js
```

So if I want to build the production project i get the error:

```
Error: Cannot find module "."<br/>
    at /Users/myname/lyrix/src/server-es5.js:1:16712<br/>
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/myname/lyrix/src/server-es5.js:1:16782)
```

Can you please help me?